# How to include headers from other packages

Tags: ros, include, catkin-package, header, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using ROS Groovy with catkin.

I created a package1 with a file1.cpp in the src directory and a header file1.h in its include/package directory.

I need to #include this header in another file2.cpp of another package2 in the same workspace and then call those declared function.

file1.cpp doesn't have any main() function. It's only a list of functions and their body definitions.

I'm not secure with this tool because everything I tried using tutorials is not working.
Please, give me full informations about what to write in every CMakeLists.txt or package.xml and how to include that header in both packages.

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/109686/how-to-include-headers-from-other-packages/) by [eds](https://answers.ros.org/users/9241/eds/) on ROS Answers with karma: 101 on 2013-12-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have to say in the manifest of package2 that it need package1 to run, if I remember right I is a dependencie. After you have rebuild It then, you should be able to include it something like "packageName/HeaderName"

---

Originally posted by [pkohout](https://answers.ros.org/users/2803/pkohout/) with karma: 336 on 2013-12-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1